# aused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.kharchaApp:layout/contact_row: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

I'm passing value in card view but this error occurs:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.kharchaApp:layout/contact_row: Binary XML file line #9 in com.kharchaApp:layout/contact_row: Error inflating class 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.kharchaApp:layout/contact_row: Error inflating class 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/transction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="transaction_chat"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        android:tag="0">
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/transction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="transaction_chat"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:strokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    android:tag="0"/>
```

You can use androidx cardView element instead of material Card View in your xml file. It will behave as same as material cardview.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting to androidx.cardview.widget.CardView solved my problem. Thank you!